# Angular JS: Controller not working

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am doing a simple example but for some reason I am unable to print the value in message variable that I pass through $scope in my controller.

please find my code as give in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3vuzfk/1/

### html page code:

```
<div ng-app>
<div>Hello AJS</div>
<div> Sum of 2 and 3 is: {{ 2 + 3}}
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        Message: {{ message }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### script.js code

```
var myController = function($scope){
    $scope.message = "My Message";
};
```

---

### My output html

Hello AJS
Sum of 2 and 3 is: 5
Message: {{ message }}

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to initalize angular by creating a module and then creating a controller in that module.

You can see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3vuzfk/4/).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "My Message Is Super Awesome";
  });
```

You can find basic examples @ [Angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/) home page.  Look at the "Add Some Control" section on that page.

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for replying. I know, creating a module may solve the issue. But I wanted to know whats wrong in this implementation. here, I have simply created a global JS function and calling it. By all means, it should work. If it cannot work, I wanted to know the reason...

Comment: Also, interesting: If I use the Google CDN, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3vuzfk/12/

Comment: yup...true. Good observation Jonathan :)

Comment: This may be oversimpifying it, but in JSFiddle I noticed that Angular JS is not set in the Frameworks section in your first JS Fiddle link.  It is in mine and Jonathan's.  And when setting it, it works.  Like I said that may be over simplifiying it.  I haven't tested it outside of JSFiddle, but if it works there, I presume it would work other places as well.

Comment: Hey Chad, thanks !!! Actually, it was the onLoad function in the Frameworks & Extensions section which was creating problem. Once you change it to "No wrap - in Head" or "No wrap - in body" it works. Even if you don't specify the Angular JS in Library. Thanks once again ...